# How can i unscrew the cap on this light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, screws, bulb

The bulbs in this light fixture I have on the ceiling on my second floor burned out. I want to take of the glass over the bulbs and replace them, but I'm having trouble unscrewing the nut that holds it in place. I just cant get enough torque with my hand. I can't stand directly underneath it because it's over some steps going down to the first floor. I don't have a pair of pliers big enough to use. What are some other ways I can unscrew it? I've attached pictures below
[image: fixture 2]
[image: fixture 1]

Comment: The real problem is staying safe while doing it.  Leaning over stairs while using both hands to undo it, sounds like you might want to use rope to tie yourself off.

Comment: 1. Try **gently** turning the glass cover to start unscrewing the final. 2. Use a rubber band or rubber jar-opener to better grip. Do *not* use pliers -- way to likely to cause damage.

Answer (score 0):

A rubber thing grippy like you use to get lids off.  Try pushing the glass dome up while you do it to take  pressure off.